# LNK1117: syntax error in option 'VERSION:.' with qmake

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, qmake

On Qt5 project using Microsoft compiler, the qmake .pro project file have

```
DATE = $$system(wmic os get LocalDateTime > $$OUT_PWD/wmic.txt)
DATE = $$cat($$OUT_PWD/wmic.txt)
DATE = $$split(DATE, ' ')
DATE = $$member(DATE, 1)
DATE = $$split(DATE, .)
DATE = $$member(DATE, 0)

DATE = $$str_member($$DATE, 0, 7)
message($${DATE})
# DATE = 20220506 # comment this line will led to error LNK1117
message($${DATE})

 YEAR = $$str_member($$DATE, 0, 3)
MONTH = $$str_member($$DATE, 4, 5)

VERSION = $${YEAR}.$${MONTH}
message($$VERSION)
```

The `DATE = 20220506` is supposed to have same value as logic above it will set. However if I comment that line it will led to error error LNK1117.

What am I missing?

I'm about to conclude `VERSION` is read at an early stage when `DATE` is not ready yet. In this case, how can I make `DATE` to be computed earlier?

Here is what I see in the QtCreator terminal:

```
20:03:54: Running steps for project project...
20:03:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" clean
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug clean
    del debug\moc_predefs.h
    del debug\moc_widget.cpp
    del debug\main.obj debug\widget.obj debug\moc_widget.obj
    del debug\project.vc.pdb debug\project.ilk debug\project.idb
    del debug\project_resource.res
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release clean
    del release\moc_predefs.h
    del release\moc_widget.cpp
    del release\main.obj release\widget.obj release\moc_widget.obj
    del release\project_resource.res
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\release\moc_predefs.h
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\release\moc_widget.cpp
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\release\main.obj
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\release\project_resource.res
    del project.vc.pdb
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\project.vc.pdb
    del project.ilk
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\project.ilk
    del project.idb
Could Not Find C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\project.idb
20:03:54: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited normally.
20:03:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\project.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:24: message(message) requires one argument.
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:26: message(message) requires one argument.
Project MESSAGE: .
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:24: message(message) requires one argument.
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:26: message(message) requires one argument.
Project MESSAGE: .
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:24: message(message) requires one argument.
C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/project.pro:26: message(message) requires one argument.
Project MESSAGE: .
20:03:54: The process "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
20:03:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" -f C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/_x64d/Makefile qmake_all

jom 1.1.3 - empower your cores

20:03:54: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited normally.
20:03:54: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" 
    C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\project.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\project -I. -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I/include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.125924.0.jom
main.cpp
    rc /NOLOGO -D_DEBUG -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -fo debug\project_resource.res project_resource.rc
    cl -BxC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\qmake.exe -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -E C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\features\data\dummy.cpp 2>NUL >debug\moc_predefs.h
    C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB --compiler-flavor=msvc --include C:/Users/user/QtProjects/project/_x64d/debug/moc_predefs.h -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/mkspecs/win32-msvc -IC:/Users/user/QtProjects/project -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/include -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtWidgets -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtGui -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtANGLE -IC:/Qt/5.15.2/msvc2019_64/include/QtCore -I. -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\ATLMFC\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\ucrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\shared" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\um" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\winrt" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.19041.0\cppwinrt" ..\widget.h -o debug\moc_widget.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\project.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\project -I. -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I/include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\widget.obj.125924.0.jom
widget.cpp
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -Zc:__cplusplus -Zi -MDd -std:c++17 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc /Fddebug\project.vc.pdb -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I..\..\project -I. -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtWidgets -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\include\QtCore -Idebug -I/include -IC:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Fodebug\ @C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\moc_widget.obj.125924.265.jom
moc_widget.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /VERSION:. /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\project.exe @C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\project.exe.125924.1109.jom
LINK : fatal error LNK1117: syntax error in option 'VERSION:.'
jom: C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\Makefile.Debug [debug\project.exe] Error 1117
jom: C:\Users\user\QtProjects\project\_x64d\Makefile [debug] Error 2
20:03:55: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project project (kit: Desktop Qt 5.15.2 MSVC2019 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
20:03:55: Elapsed time: 00:02.
```

Comment: What *is* the error you get? Please copy-paste it (as text) into your questions. And also please copy-paste the full output the `.pro` file gives you (the file that gives you the error, not the one that works).

Comment: By the way, you might also want to print out `DATE` between each and every step, preferably with quotes or something around it so that it's easy to see if there's leading or trailing spaces or something which might throw your parsing of.

Comment: Updated question. Anything else I can add? You mean to print out DATE with `message(\"$${DATE}\")`?

Comment: Yes exactly, and do it *every* time you assign to `DATE`.

Comment: I think `VERSION` is kinda special variable and is read before those values are available